# How to Query HR Schema from R?

Tags: r, oracle, odbc, rstudio

I'm new to both R and Oracle. I'm using ODBC package for connectivity from R to Oracle. I installed the server and in Rstudio I opened a connection to Oracle database using ODBC DSN with hr username. When I typed dbListTables(conn, schema='HR'), all tables belongs to HR schema were shown, but when I typed a basic query with dbSendQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM employees;") no row fetched. How can I query HR tables properly?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM HR.employees`? or `SELECT * FROM "HR.employees"`

Comment: Yes, I tried this.

Comment: Have you tired `dbGetQuery` instead of `dbSendQuery`?

Comment: It worked, thank you so much.